# python random arithmetic game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, arithmetic-expressions

I'd like to create a program that generates two random numbers and applies a random arithmetic function to them and then prints the answer.
So far I've made the numbers and the calculations but I do not know how to print the sum out or generate an answer.

```
from random import randint
import random
arithmatic = ['+','-','*','/']
beginning = (randint(1,9))
calculation =(random.choice(arithmatic))
end = (randint(1,9))
print (beginning)
print (calculation)
print (end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

# Generate your first number
>>> first = random.randint(1,9)
>>> first
1

# Generate your second number
>>> second = random.randint(1,9)
>>> second
5
```

Now map all the operators in your list to the actual operator functions.

```
import operator
ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div}
```

Now you can randomly select an operator

```
>>> op = random.choice(ops.keys())
>>> op
'+'
```

Then call the function from your dictionary.

```
>>> ops[op](first,second)
6
```

Comment: But I can only getting it working in python 2 not 3.

Comment: @futureprogress Why is that? Can you post the lines of code that are causing the problem, and the full error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

instead, consider making the operations you choose from true functions:

```
import operator
arithmetic = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.div]
# ...
print calculation(beginning, end)
```